# Using trunc and concatenate command with Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, concatenation, truncate

```
select EDR_Process_Time, MSISDN1, Total_payment/Total_data_MB from 
(

    select trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.process_time) as EDR_Process_Time, M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.MSISDN as MSISDN1, trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.CDR_start_Date), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.served_msisdn, sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee_1) as Charge_fee_CDR, 
    sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee/100) as Total_Payment,
    sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.amount/1048576) as Total_data_MB,
    from (M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V 
    left join M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V on concat(trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.process_time), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.MSISDN) = concat(trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.CDR_start_date), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.served_MSISDN))

    group by trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.Process_time), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.MSISDN
group by trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.CDR_start_Date), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.Served_MSISDN
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, wrong syntax at `M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.sum((charge_fee)/100)`  and other similar expressions.
If you want `sum` of `charge_fee`/100 column of the `M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V` table (view) it must 
be

```
sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee/100)
```

Next, you can not use an alias in the same `SELECT` list where it was introduced. `Total_Payment` and `Total_data_MB` should only apprear in expressions at outer `SELECT`.

Assign aliases to the every expression of the inner `select`, an alias to the inner `select` itself and use list  of qualified names and expresions using those names instead of `*` in the outer `select`.

Also, it looks like `GROUP BY` is missing.

```
select t.process_time, t.MSISDN, t.sum1, 
  t.Total_Payment,
  t.Total_data_MB,
  t.Total_Payment/t.Total_data_MB as cost_per_MB  
from (
   select 
     M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.process_time,
     M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.MSISDN,
     sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee_1) as sum1, 
     (coalesce(sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee_1),0) + coalesce(sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee/100),0)) as Total_Payment,
     sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.amount)/1048576 as Total_data_MB
     -- Don't you mean
     --GROUP BY M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.process_time, M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.MSISDN 
   from (M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V 
          left join M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V on concat(trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.process_time), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.MSISDN) = concat(trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.CDR_start_date), M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.served_MSISDN)
   ) t
)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks.....tried the suggested corrections, i still get the following error                                   TOTAL_DATA_MB": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Hi .....Made the changes as suggested. Still struggling. Glad if you can assist some more please.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of functions is wrong. Use trunc function as `trunc(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_EDR_DETAILS_V.process_time)`. Usege of sum is wrong too. You also should change them to `sum(M_MOBILEMV.Q_RA_CDR_DETAILS_V.charge_fee_1`.

Comment: THanks....tried the suggestions. I still get the following error:TOTAL_DATA_MB": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Give an alias to outer query's "from" (biggest brackets) part and select column with alias. `select t.EDR_Process_Time, t.MSISDN1, t.Total_payment/t.Total_data_MB from (...) as t`

Comment: Hi Burak...have done that. Can you identify any issue that still persist with the query i have updated here?

Comment: There is a case problem in query. `Total_payment` in select, `Total_Payment` in subquery (p is the problem). If there is an error, please write it here.